# Creating a different copy template from a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA macro which helps me to create new sheets in my workbook every time i enter a new column. What i want to change is to create a new sheet but copying a template sheet for that new sheet.

I basically create a "home sheet" where i will divide the curriculum into lessons, then i want the script to run and create a lesson plan sheet for each lesson.

```
Sub add()

Call CreateWorksheets(Sheets("Lesson List").Range("B2:XFD2"))

End Sub

Sub CreateWorksheets(Names_Of_Sheets As Range)
Dim No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added As Integer
Dim Sheet_Name As String
Dim i As Integer

No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added = Names_Of_Sheets.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added

Sheet_Name = Names_Of_Sheets.Cells(1, i).Value

If (Sheet_Exists(Sheet_Name) = False) And (Sheet_Name <> "") Then
    Worksheets.add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)).Name = Sheet_Name
End If

Next i

End Sub

Function Sheet_Exists(WorkSheet_Name As String) As Boolean
Dim Work_sheet As Worksheet

Sheet_Exists = False

For Each Work_sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Work_sheet.Name = WorkSheet_Name Then
        Sheet_Exists = True
    End If

Next

End Function
```

When i try to use the copy function i still get an error:

```
Sub add()

Call CreateWorksheets(Sheets("Lesson List").Range("B2:XFD2"))

End Sub

Sub CreateWorksheets(Names_Of_Sheets As Range)
Dim No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added As Integer
Dim Sheet_Name As String
Dim i As Integer
'determine the number of sheets to create
No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added = Names_Of_Sheets.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added
'lable each sheet
Sheet_Name = Names_Of_Sheets.Cells(1, i).Value

If (Sheet_Exists(Sheet_Name) = False) And (Sheet_Name <> "") Then
    Worksheets("Lesson Plan Template").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Name = Sheet_Name
       
    End If

Next i

End Sub

Function Sheet_Exists(WorkSheet_Name As String) As Boolean
Dim Work_sheet As Worksheet

Sheet_Exists = False

For Each Work_sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Work_sheet.Name = WorkSheet_Name Then
        Sheet_Exists = True
    End If

Next

End Function
```

Comment: what's the source of your template sheet?

Comment: It is a different sheet in the workbook.

Comment: You need to specify that in the code.

Comment: I have tried it please see my question with the updated code - it still results in an error

Comment: Can you send the file to me?

Comment: Sure, do i just add it to the original post?

Comment: Check the answer ..It working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Check now.

```
Sub add()

Call CreateWorksheets(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E12"))

End Sub

Sub CreateWorksheets(Names_Of_Sheets As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added As Integer
Dim Sheet_Name As String
Dim i As Integer
'determine the number of sheets to create
No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added = Names_Of_Sheets.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added
'lable each sheet
Sheet_Name = Names_Of_Sheets.Cells(1, i).Value  'Use 2 instead of 1

If (Sheet_Exists(Sheet_Name) = False) And (Sheet_Name <> "") Then
    Sheets.add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)).Name = Sheet_Name
    Sheet1.Cells.Copy           'Use Sheets("lesson plan template").cells.copy
    Sheets(Sheet_Name).Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
End Sub



Function Sheet_Exists(WorkSheet_Name As String) As Boolean
Dim Work_sheet As Worksheet

Sheet_Exists = False

For Each Work_sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Work_sheet.Name = WorkSheet_Name Then
        Sheet_Exists = True
    End If

 Next

 End Function
```

Comment: thank you, it still copies or create blank pages, when i change 

sheet1.cells.copy

It replace everything in my template sheet rather thank copying the content from there to the newly created sheets

Comment: So i will start with two sheets in my workbook. One sheet will be a lesson list, the second one will be a lesson plan template. Whenever i enter a new column cell in the sheet "lesson plan" on row 2, i want to see a new sheet tab. The lable of the tab/ sheet should be that of which was entered into the cell on the lesson list row two. The content on the newly "created" sheet should be a copy of what is found on the "lesson plan template" sheet.

Comment: Check the answer now..I have add a video of code too..

Comment: Video Link: https://www.facebook.com/mdismail.hosen.7/videos/2665312623735902/?notif_id=1600097545098111&notif_t=video_processed&ref=notif

Answer (score 0):

I made progress with my original code:

```
Sub Add_New_Lesson()

Call Copy_Lesson_Template(Sheets("Lesson List").Range("B2:XFD2"))


End Sub


Sub Copy_Lesson_Template(Names_Of_Sheets As Range)

Dim No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added As Integer
Dim Sheet_Name As String
Dim i As Integer

No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added = Names_Of_Sheets.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To No_Of_Sheets_to_be_Added
Sheet_Name = Names_Of_Sheets.Cells(1, i).Value


If (Sheet_Exists(Sheet_Name) = False) And (Sheet_Name <> "") Then
Worksheets("Lesson Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = (Sheet_Name)

End If

Next i

End Sub


Function Sheet_Exists(WorkSheet_Name As String) As Boolean
Dim Work_sheet As Worksheet

Sheet_Exists = False

For Each Work_sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Work_sheet.Name = WorkSheet_Name Then
        Sheet_Exists = True
    End If

Next

End Function
```